# SurfaceView or TextureView combination

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, textureview

I am trying to **apply real-time effects to camera preview and show in multiple views**, how can I do?
(just like the [camera2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.camera2))  ([snapshot](https://lh4.ggpht.com/2RVnMZoCuY9NUdRcPkXGx9mt0TgMOps_f1fdCaGPoDzloPXyTTF7HkqfBTgnGJEqOII=h310-rw))

I know 2 approaches to show real-time effects on camera preivew if no ScrollView involved on the left side.

- Use [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) and [setRenderer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderer(android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer)). Bind SurfaceTexture as GLES external texture, and use GLSL(OpenGL Shading Language) to apply effects.
- Use [TextureView](http://web.mit.edu/majapw/MacData/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). It is more complex because need to setup EGLContext/EGLSurface and do thread management.

However, I don't know how to make ScrollView with real-time effect items overlay GLES composition.

1. **Should I choose GLSurfaceView (for performance) or TextureView (for flexble) to implement the ScrollView**?  Which one is better solution and why?
2. **Is it possible to share one EGL context/surface among multiple views?** If yes, any code snippets to refer to?

After googling and reading nice [Graphics architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) article and [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) project, I still have no idea ...
Maybe I miss something important, dose someone point me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SurfaceView and scrolling don't go well together, because the SurfaceView has two parts -- the Surface and the View -- and movement of one tends to lag behind movement of the other.  The View is rendered by the app, but the Surface is composited by SurfaceFlinger, so window movement has to get passed through the Window Manager.  TextureView doesn't have this problem, but does introduce some additional overhead.

If you want it to look good when scrolling, you'll probably want a TextureView.

It is possible for multiple EGL contexts to share data, and it is possible to use a single EGL context to render to more than one surface.  [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) has examples of both ("show + capture camera" uses GLSurfaceView and a shared EGL context, "continuous capture" uses SurfaceView and a single EGL context; both activities render to an on-screen surface and an off-screen surface).

All hardware-accelerated Views do their own EGL context management, and there's no reason to mess with that if you're rendering onto SurfaceView or TextureView.

If you're planning to draw multiple versions of the live camera preview in real time, you'll get the best performance by rendering them all yourself in a single scene.  Rendering multiple TextureViews will be less efficient.  Depending on your UI choices, this might mean handling the item drawing and scrolling yourself instead of handing it off to ListView.  (At the very least, you'd want to ensure that you're only live-updating the thumbnails that are actually on screen.)

Comment: So, if I have already used GlSurfaceView in the back, I better choose TextureView on top of that? **Create second EGL context for TextureView surface and share the state with GLSurfaceView context?** Then, instead of multiple TextureViews, just **render multiple quads with GLES on one TextureView inside a ScrollView?** Please correct me if I am wrong, thanks.

Comment: Another thought. For better performance and more control over the rendering process, is it possible to use 2 SurfaceViews to achieve this? (Then I can use a single EGL context to render 2 surface just like "show + capture camera").

Comment: If you want to use GLSurfaceView, rather than plain SurfaceView, you're stuck with multiple EGL contexts sharing state.  If you use plain SurfaceView for the back, you can use a single EGL context.  TextureView + ScrollView seems reasonable, though I haven't tried it myself.  Using two SurfaceViews is possible if you set the Z-ordering to position one in front of the other, but you can take a performance hit if the number of surfaces composited by SurfaceFlinger exceeds the overlay plane count.  (See the Grafika "multi-surface" activity.)

Comment: Any possible to exceed the overlay plane on Android 4.4 devices if I use 2 SurfaceViews in this case? I mean kitkat devices typically support 4 overlay planes, and camera is full-screen (without status bar, with a virtual navigation bar), so the Hardware Composer state would be "SurfaceView, SurfaceView, xxxActivity, NavigationBar" ordered from back to front. It looks just meet the requirement.

Comment: If so, 2 SurfaceViews seems the most efficient way (consider performance and easy single EGL context). Howerer, SurfaceView’s "surfce" is difficult to use inside a ScrollView. Therefore, surfaceview + textureview would be the better solution? Any advice?

Comment: I think you're going to have to experiment a little.  The "show + capture camera" activity in Grafika got rewritten about five times while I was trying to figure out how various pieces could fit together.  You can use a single EGL context to render to a SurfaceView and a TextureView; the EGL context "built in" to TextureView is used to render the content you drew on its Surface.  (See the EGL setup in `Renderer#run()` in "Simple GL in TextureView" activity; you could use a pre-existing EGLCore.)

Comment: @fadden
Is it possible to transplant the class TextureView to Android Honeycomb?