# eglSwapBuffers blocked in GLSurfaceView onDrawFrame

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, egl, textureview

As my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376340/surfaceview-or-textureview-combination), I am trying "`GLSurfaceView + TextureView`" to show camera preview in one GLSurfaceView and multiple TextureViews, but facing some problems...

In GLSurfaceView render thread, I tried to share built-in EGLContext to TextureView, create a EGL surface by TextureView's surfaceTexture, then use GLES to draw on it.

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {
        // GLES draw on GLSurfaceView
        renderToTextureView();
    }

    private void renderToTextureView() {
        saveEGLState();
        for(TextureViewItem item : mTextureViewItemList) {
            item.render(mSavedEglContext);
        }
        restoreEGLState();
    }

    private void saveEGLState() {
        mSavedEglDisplay = EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay();
        mSavedEglContext = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext();
        mSavedEglDrawSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_DRAW);
        mSavedEglReadSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_READ);
    }

    private void restoreEGLState() {
        if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mSavedEglDisplay, mSavedEglDrawSurface, mSavedEglReadSurface, mSavedEglContext)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed");
        }
    }

    public class TextureViewItem implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
        private static EglCore sEglCore;
        private WindowSurface mWindowSurface;

        public void render(EGLContext sharedContext) {
            if(mSavedSurfaceTexture == null) return;
            getWindowSurface(sharedContext).makeCurrent();
            // GLES draw on TextureView
            getWindowSurface(sharedContext).swapBuffers();
        }

        private WindowSurface getWindowSurface(EGLContext sharedContext) {
            if(sEglCore == null) {
                sEglCore = new EglCore(sharedContext, EglCore.FLAG_TRY_GLES3);
            }
            if(mWindowSurface == null) {
                mWindowSurface = new WindowSurface(mEglCore, mSavedSurfaceTexture);
            }
            return mWindowSurface;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture st, int width, int height) {
            if (mSavedSurfaceTexture == null) {
                mSavedSurfaceTexture = st;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture st) {       
            if (mWindowSurface != null) {
                mWindowSurface.release();
            }
            if (sEglCore != null) {
                sEglCore.release();
            }

            mSavedSurfaceTexture = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine except press "back" key. I call GLSurfaceView's onPause() when the activity pauses, it caused swapBuffers (EGL14.eglSwapBuffers) won't return...

Some suspected logcat messages also
`W/WindowManager(1077): Window freeze timeout expired.`
`I/WindowManager(1077): Screen frozen for +2s42ms due to Window ..`

Anyone knows why? And any way to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: (1) EGL contexts are fairly expensive.  On older devices you were only allowed to have one per process.  The code snippet looks like you're creating a new one every frame; if so, don't do that.  Just use `makeCurrent()` to switch.  (2) `swapBuffers()` is actually an "add buffer to queue" call, and it will stall after a few calls if nothing is reading the buffers from the queue.  I believe it runs on the main UI thread, so if you're in onPause() it can't do anything.  (I dislike GLSurfaceView -- shared EGL state and threading issues get unnecessarily complicated.  Plain SurfaceView is easier.)

Comment: for (2), you mean when onPause(), the TextureView doesn't consume any frame in BufferQueue (on the UI thread), so elgSwapBuffers() will block and wait for free buffers?

Comment: If I use GLSurfaceView, any good way to fix this problem? Is there similar solution in Grafika? Because I try GPUImage (https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage), which is GLSurfaceView based framework, to apply effects on camera preview. Thanks, Fadden.

Comment: I dig into GLSurfaceView.java source code and try to find some clues. It also calls elgSwapBuffers() after onDrawFrame(), but single GLSurfaceView won't incur the same problem when onPause()... It's really weird...

Comment: Yes, if the BufferQueue is full, eglSwapBuffers() will block.  There's a chance that fixing issue #1 will fix #2.  Make sure you look at a stack trace to confirm the state of the main UI thread -- it's possible I'm off.

Comment: For #1, I make all TextureViews share with one EGL context. Unfortunately, it won't fix #2... I find TextureViewGLActivity.java of Grafika also use GLES to draw on TextureView. Why this won't block in swapBuffers() when activity onPause()? It seems has the similar condition, the TextureView display on UI thread, and BufferQueue is full  (producer renders frames is faster than consumer). Please help point me in the right direction...Thanks.

Comment: I think I may have confused the issue.  GLSurfaceView is synchronous and can stall.  TextureView is asynchronous and won't, unless you have a specific Android release (4.4.0) which mistakenly made it synchronous.  Note the comments above `doAnimation()` in TextureViewGLActivity.java -- one of the reasons that activity exists is to test this.  If "Simple GL in TextureView" looks like a spastic nightmare, your device is working correctly.  If it's smooth, you have the bug.

Comment: In any event, TextureViewGLActivity draws as fast as it can until it's either told to stop or the TextureView becomes invalid.  `eglSwapBuffers()` will return if the BufferQueue is freed out from under it, so if the activity just stops without telling the renderer thread you will get the correct behavior.  (The other thing the Activity was written to do was exercise this behavior; see comments near top of class.)  What is your UI thread doing?  Waiting for the renderer thread to halt?

Comment: I updated code snippets and let me explain more clearly as I can. In order to show camera preview to one GLSurfaceView and multiple TextureViews, I draw TextureViews within in GLSurfaceView's render thread for sharing built-in EGLContext to TextureView. So in onDrawFrame(), I share one eglContext with multiple TextureViews and every TextureView has its own eglSurface backed by its SurfaceTexture. Then do some GLES draw on it and eglSwapBuffers to add this frame to BufferQueue.

Comment: When activity pausing, I call GLSurfaceView.onPause() before activity super.onPause(). If I comment renderToTextureView(), it works fine, which means, GLSurfaceView render thread stops correct and TextureView's onSurfaceTextureDestroyed() is called in UI thread. However, if renderToTextureView() involves, it causes 2 wrong results based on timing.

Comment: 1. swapBuffers() won't return, which means, it blocks in render thread and I can't get onSurfaceTextureDestroyed() callback to release resources correctly, which means next time onResume(), all views stuck.
2. onPause() happens just after swapBuffers(), I will get `E/libEGL(30247): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`, `E/GLConsumer(30247): [unnamed-30247-1] detachFromContext: invalid current EGLDisplay`, it looks like TextureView destroySurface in the wrong (GLSurfaceView's) eglContext. I am really frustrated, please help.

Comment: Look at `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()` in https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureViewGLActivity.java . Note that it doesn't do any real work, and doesn't wait for the renderer thread -- just signals the renderer thread to stop. It returns "true" (based on the UI-switchable `sReleaseInCallback`) to cause the framework to tear down the TextureView immediately, which causes `eglSwapBuffers()` to un-stick when you have the 4.4.0 bug.  Something similar may help you, but not if you're waiting for the renderer thread to stop before the TextureViews are torn down.

Comment: As far as I knew, the right behavior of TextureViewGLActivity pausing should be: activity `onPause()` -> `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()` TextureView SurfaceTexture is about to be destroyed -> return true cause SurfaceTexture destroyed -> `eglSwapBuffers()` returns but throw an exception. In my case, it is very weird... **I can't get TextureView's onSurfaceTextureDestroyed() in UI thread and eglSwapBuffers() always block in the render thread**. Did I misuse something or miss something? Thanks again.